# How to use variables in "EXECUTE format()" in plpgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, stored-functions

I want to update a column in table `stats` with the specific column being a parameter, then return the updated value of that column [only has 1 row]:

```
CREATE FUNCTION grow(col varchar) RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
tmp int;
BEGIN
    tmp := (EXECUTE format(
            'UPDATE stats SET %I = %I + 1
            RETURNING %I',
            col, col, col
            )
    );
    RETURN tmp;
END;
```

As a whole, I'm not even sure if this is best way to do what I want, any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: can't you use [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ecpg-dynamic.html) ? Have a look at section 33.5.3

Comment: I'm just curious about your overall design... Based on the clues in your question, this is a table that holds stats and the stored procedure is meant to "grow" a specific stat that is passed in? Is there a reason you decided to go with columns, instead of a lookup table (i.e. just two columns: stat_name, stat_value)? That is much more flexible and conventional than using columns... Plus, no need for dynamic SQL then.

Comment: @cha: There is no `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` in plpgsql. What you link to is part of *ECPG* (Embedded SQL in C)!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You *can* do that. Use the [`INTO` keyword of the `EXECUTE` statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION grow(_col text, OUT tmp integer)
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN

EXECUTE format(
 'UPDATE stats
  SET    %1$I = %1$I + 1
  RETURNING %1$I'
 , _col)
INTO tmp;

END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT grow('counter');
```

Using an [`OUT` parameter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) to simplify overall.
[`format()` syntax explained in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT).

You could just run the `UPDATE` instead of a function call:

```
UPDATE stats SET counter = counter + 1 RETURNING counter;
```

There are not many scenarios where the function with dynamic SQL isn't just needless complication.

#### Alternative design

If at all possible consider a different table layout: rows instead of columns (as suggested by @Ruslan). Allows any number of counters:

```
CREATE TABLE stats (
  tag text PRIMARY KEY
, counter int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

Call:

```
UPDATE stats
SET    counter = counter + 1
WHERE  tag = 'counter1'
RETURNING counter;
```

Or maybe consider a dedicated [`SEQUENCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html) for counting ...

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware of a few things you used. Had no luck trying to look them up, still one thing I'm lost at, the "%1$I" expression. Is there a place I can go to read more about them? Thanks again!

Comment: @House3272: The `1$` in the middle references the first parameter provided. I added a link to the manual for details on `format()`.